# OS X to iOS communication via USB?

Tags: ios, cocoa, macos, usb

Is there currently an Apple-approved (or at least tolerated) strategy to transfer high-bandwidth data over USB from an iOS device to OS X?  Is this even allowed as an MFi program developer?

Comment: Hmmm, iOS 5 is "PC Free". They even made an icon with a pair of scissors and a cable. Are you sure you want this?

Comment: This is highly desirable for solutions like reliable streaming video (say, a secondary monitor solution) that need high bandwidth and are not able to depend on WiFi... even if it's not the primary communication channel.

Comment: If streaming video is the solution you're actually interested in, Apple's own Digital AV Adapter would seem to provide what you need.  Interestingly, just announced today, Apple will be supporting Airplay over Bluetooth: http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2011/12/apple-extending-airplay-over-low-power-low-latency-bluetooth-40.ars

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [peertalk](http://rsms.me/peertalk/) is interesting. "PeerTalk is a iOS and OS X Cocoa library for communicating over USB and TCP."

Comment: Hey, I'm actually looking for more information about PeerTalk. I've been looking for this EXACT solution for some time. I'm running xCode 4.0 on Snow Leopard, and it won't compile (it says it needs Lion and xCode 4.3). Anyway, from what I've heard I thought this was impossible without some sort of MFi license. Does this work on non-jailbroken phones? I've been looking through the source and I haven't yet been able to identify the key ingredient- how he establishes a connection over USB. Can anyone give me a leg up here?

Comment: Actually, I think the next comment down just answered my question. Good post!

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at this project from iOSDevCamp 2010 if you want to transfer data over USB:

http://maxweisel.com/blog/2010/08/iosdevcamp2010-hackathon-ios-usb-sync/

Perhaps this doesn't map to what you're actually trying to do, though.

Answer (score 0):

There is no legitimate way to do this using the public iOS SDK at the moment.

It is also impossible to do that within the MFi, unless you want to put a peripheral in between.